# Converting Pandas daily timestep to 52 week per year timestep with the last week of 8 days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe with the index of daily timestep just as below:

```
oldman.head()

         Value
date              
1992-01-01  1080.4
1992-01-02  1080.4
1992-01-03  1080.4
1992-01-04  1080.0
1992-01-05  1079.6
...
```

starting from 1992-01-01 to 2016-12-31. I want to extract weekly mean values of each year. However, my weeks should be in special way. There should be 52 weeks in a year with 365 days but with the **last week of 8 days**! The first week should start from January 1st of each year.

I am wondering how am I supposed to extract this kind of weeks from a daily timestep data.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the note. Just was looking forward to getting something clean and neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified COLDSPEED's solution a bit an added in the last week as 8 days. It's worth noting that on leap years that last "week" is actually 9 days. The following example will only work when you include all of a year. The reason for this is that my function assumes the last row in the groupby is actually the last week of the year.

```
#make some data
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("1992-1-1","1992-12-31"))
df["value"] = 1

#add a counting variable
df["count"] = 1
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y'))\
  .resample('7D')\
  .sum()\
  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)\

def chop_last_week(df):
    df1=df.copy()
    df1.iloc[-2] += df1.iloc[-1]
    return df1.iloc[:-1]

df = df.groupby(df.index.year)\
        .apply(chop_last_week)\
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df["mean"] = df["value"]/df["count"]
df.tail(5)
```

It's not the cleanest solution but it runs quickly.

Comment: Thanks! seems perfect expect a bit messy. However, nothing more I can expect at this time.